# Google API AuthorizationCodeFlow

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, google-api, jboss7.x

I'm really struggling getting a simple Google OAuth transaction going. I'm using Java EE, and running on JBoss v7.1, and programming it all in Eclipse Indigo.

Here's the code. All it's doing is running up the servlet when you access /index, and it should establish an AuthorisationCodeFlow. It doesn't; the code hangs (when uploading to the server) at

```
    privateAuthorizationCodeFlow flow;
```

.

```
    package com.pjm.servlets;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeFlow;

    @WebServlet("/index")
    public class IndexController extends HttpServlet {          
        private static final String clientId = "1234.apps.googleusercontent.com";
        private static final String clientSecret = "12345abcde";
        private static final String callbackUrl = "http://localhost:8080/ProjectA/callback";
        private AuthorizationCodeFlow flow;

        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {       
            String url =        flow.newAuthorizationUrl().setState("xyz").setRedirectUri("https://client.example.com/rd").build();
        }
```

Here's the short version of the exception log:

```
    EXCEPTION

    javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception

    ROOT CAUSE

    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/auth/oauth2/AuthorizationCodeFlow
    com.pjm.servlets.IndexController.doGet(IndexController.java:30)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)

    ROOT CAUSE

    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeFlow from [Module "deployment.PmWebProjectB.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
    org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)           org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    com.pjm.servlets.IndexController.doGet(IndexController.java:30)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
```

It looks like I haven't uploaded the correct jar files to the right places, but I've done the usual and uploaded them in Eclipse, which seems happy. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Your jars are not available on jboss. How you are deploying app to jboss via eclipse or exporting project as jar(if yes then you need to add jar while creating war)?

Comment: Hi sudmong, thanks for your reply! I'm deploying via eclipse.

Comment: can you see google authflow jars along with your app code on server's deployment directory where your app is deployed? I suspect its not there.

Comment: It means your have added those jars on your build path from external location and you are able to compile your code. To have those jar in run time, Add those jars to your apps's WEB-INF/lib folder,eclipse will push those with app. Also update the build path to take those from this new location.

Comment: Thanks again for your continued help! The relevant jar was already added to the build path. Having done what you've suggested, (adding the jar also to the WEB-INF/lib directory), jboss is now kicking up a fuss, saying something like: "WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry gson-2.1.jar in '/C:/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/dep
loyments/WebProjectB.war/WEB-INF/lib/google-api-client-1.9.0-beta.jar'  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference", but the app is deployed (and gives the same error as quoted before).

Comment: Looks some issue jboss 7 may be. Export war of your project and try it on some other server, tomcat or jboss6 or try it to jboss 7 explicitly not from eclipse. Then see what is the issue.